# High percentage of missing values - is EM still possible?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, missing-data

I have a dataset with 500K individuals and 200 variables. The problem we have is that most of the variables have a high percentage of missing values (~20 variables are 100% populated but other variables have less than 20% inputted values).

Before looking at the dataset, I was thinking about using the EM algorithm to populate the missing fields (at least for some of the most important variables). But looking at the high percentage of missing values, I am now wondering if it's still possible...
Do you have a statistical method to estimate what would be the minimum % of missing values to have to have significant results? 
If EM is not possible, do you know another methods to deal with this high proportion of missings?

Thank you for your help!

Kind regards,

Marion

Comment: Whether or not EM operates does not depend on the percentage of missing values but on the underlying model. What is your statistical model? Obviously, the more missing values, the more imprecise the inference.